# $A.enqueueAction not returned in jquery context

Tags: lightning-aura-components, partner-communities

**Update: My Code (DX generated) is saved in a github repo with good README => [here](https://github.com/Xixiao007/TestLC)**

I try to create a Lightning Component (LC) using an external js library [jstree](https://github.com/vakata/jstree), which is jquery dependent.

**Original issue**

If this LC is added **in partner portal home page**, `$A.enqueueAction` has no data returned once the function is constructed inside a jquery function.

When this LC is added to other pages, such as `account` or `contact` record page, this issue does not appear, i.e. `$A.enqueueAction` returns well.

I thought the issue roots from jquery v.s. LC namespace conflicting, but it seems not as my troubleshooting goes.

**My troubleshooting progress**

The issue most likely comes from [Modifying Components Outside the Framework Lifecycle](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_mod_ext_js.htm).

[This article](http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.fi/2015/06/lightning-components-and-unobtrusive.html) has similar issue as I am having.

A similar [stackoverflow question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/148009/a-enqueueaction-not-working-with-a-getcallback) here.

**Current issue**

After troubleshooting, I still don't figure out the correct way to use `$A.getCallback` in my code.

I have used it in my `controller.js` (code attached below). `$A.enqueueAction` returns well, but a page error pops up:

`This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Assertion Failed!: $A.getCallback(): 'callback' must be a valid Function : false`

In addition, I still don't know why this issue only appears **in partner portal** as stated in `Original issue` section above.

Console screenshot[image]

**My code below, simplified version**

My Code (DX generated) is saved in a github repo with good README => [here](https://github.com/Xixiao007/TestLC)

cmp file

```
<ltng:require styles="/resource/ref/themes/default/style.min.css" scripts="{!join(',', '/resource/ref/jquery-3.3.1.min.js', '/resource/ref/jstree.js' )}"
afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.resourceLoaded}" />

<div id="render"></div>
</aura:component>
```

Controller.js (format is aligned with [jstree instruction](https://github.com/vakata/jstree#populating-the-tree-using-a-callback-function)

```
({
  resourceLoaded: function(component, event, helper) {
    console.log("Resources loaded succesfully!");
    $("#render").jstree({
      core: {
        data: function(node, cb) {
          if (node.id === "#") {
            console.log("root node");
            cb([
              {
                text: "Document",
                children: true,
                data: {
                  uri:
                    "whatever-REST-endpoint-URL"
                }
              }
            ]);
          } else {
            console.log("sub node");
            //use $A.getCallback here, but page throws error 
            $A.getCallback(helper.getLazyResponse(component, node.data.uri, cb));
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }
});
```

helper.js

```
({
  getLazyResponse: function(cmp, url, cb) {
    var action = cmp.get("c.getStructureInfo");
    action.setParams({ URL: url });
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
      var state = response.getState();
      if (state === "SUCCESS") {
        var result = response.getReturnValue();
        console.log("Data: \n" + result);
        cb(JSON.parse(result));
      } else {
        console.log("error");
      }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
    console.log("ajax call fired");
  }
});
```

Apex controller

```
public with sharing class SPWebServiceController {

  @AuraEnabled
  public static String getStructureInfo(String URL){
    return 'hello';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$A.getCallback needs a function; instead, you're calling a function and returning a null value. It's also not appropriate here, because you're not using a callback at the point you're trying to use $A.getCallback; you want the code in the helper to trigger immediately.

Your code should be simply:

```
helper.getLazyResponse(component, node.data.uri, cb);
```

That said, I realize you're trying to build a callback (cb), so you do actually need to get a callback handle here. Thus, your code changes to:

```
helper.getLazyResponse(component, node.data.uri, $A.getCallback(cb));
```

---

The data element used in jstree is itself a callback, and so needs to be wrapped up in an $A.getCallback as well:

```
({
  resourceLoaded: function(component, event, helper) {
    console.log("Resources loaded succesfully!");
    // var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    $("#render").jstree({
      core: {
        data: $A.getCallback(function(node, cb) {
          if (node.id === "#") {
            console.log("root node");
            cb([
              {
                text: "Documents",
                children: true,
                data: {
                  uri:
                    "https://finxxi.sharepoint.com/sites/poc/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Shared Documents')"
                }
              }
            ]);
          } else {
            console.log("sub node");
            helper.getLazyResponse(component, node.data.uri, $A.getCallback(cb));
          }
        })
      },
      plugins: ["wholerow"]
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I have tried to wrap cb in $A.getCallback, exactly as you proposed. Though the error is gone,  the `$A.enqueueAction` still does not return :(..

Comment: @XiXiao (removed prior comment). Just saw your edit. I'll try it in my org.

Comment: Thanks! I am also testing to make sure the code in repo repreduce my issue

Comment: Repo code is tested. Issue reproducing steps are in README. Btw, this issue only appears in `partner community page` (details are  in the `repo README.md` too)

Comment: @XiXiao I'm kind of embarrassed it took me this long to see it. The data function itself needs to fire an action, so it has to be in a $A.getCallback. See edit. The $A.getCallback(cb) is optional, but doesn't hurt anything.

Comment: It is really a big hand @sfdcfox , it works! Two silly questions: 1. how do you know `The data element is itself a callback` ? 2. why my original LC works without `$A.getCallback` in `account` record page while not in `partner community` page?

Comment: @XiXiao (1) Because you're handing it a function that's called later. (2) It likely works because something else also triggers a life cycle change, so the queued event eventually fires. Just because you're not within the LC life cycle doesn't mean that the action still isn't queued, just that it won't be processed until the next server-side action is called. When it doubt, just use $A.getCallback. It never hurts.